# do I need HTMLpurifier in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, htmlpurifier

I am developing a PHP application using Codeigniter framework and it is time now for the security reviews.. I got many recommendations to use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) library if i want the best protection I can get.. is this true? do I really need this library or are there better options? I appreciate your thoughts on this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know this for myself too.  I know that Codeigniter has there own way of checking for html in there [form validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html), if your using a form and [XSS Filtering](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html) in there Security Class.  It may not be the best but it should be able to help you until you find your correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is HTMLPurifier working, but it will be probably best solution than built-in XSS protection.
You can read more about the Codeigniter XSS vulnerability in [this article](http://ponderwell.net/2010/08/codeigniter-xss-protection-is-good-but-not-enough-by-itself/). Maybe it is fixed in the latest version, but if you really want good protection, use something more powerfull than CI Security Class (you can build your own class).

Comment: If you suggest building your own class to 'improve' the one found in a a top 10 framework, you better really know what you're doing.